# How create another column (list Data tibble) using filters text into another column

Tags: r, functional-programming, purrr

I am Peruvian and I'm learning to program in R.
I need to get another column similar to Data.
This column should be created using filters (column x have filter text) about column Data (list tibble)

This work good!

```
DataFiltrada<-NULL; 
for (i in 1:nrow(Data)) {DataFiltrada[[i]]<-Data$Data[[i]] %>% filter_(Data$x[i])}
Data$DataFiltrada<-DataFiltrada
Data
```

[image: Resultado Ideal]

How to can use functional programming with purrr in r ?

Please your help!
Thanks!

```
Data<-
tibble(
       x = c("x == 'a' & y ==  1","x == 'b' & y ==  2","x == 'c' & y ==  3"), 
       name = c("Data1", "Data2", "Data1")
       ) %>% 
left_join(
          list("Data1" = tibble(x = c("a","b","c"), y = c(1,2,3)),
               "Data2" = tibble(x = c("a","b"), y = c(1,2))) %>% 
            enframe(name = "name", value = "Data")
          )
```

This is my Data...

[image: This is my Data]

Comment: This data makes no sense to me. You `left_join` a 3-row frame (with textual code?) with a 2-row frame based on no common values, so your 2-row frame arbitrarily becomes 3 rows. I'm inferring that you intend to *evaluate* the code in `x` with what is embedded within `Data`, but there are often gotchas and almost certainly performance penalties when doing this. Can you explain what your original problem is to explain why this would be your path for solution?

Comment: Hi. Thank for you answer.

Comment: I modified my question. I added a picture with the result that I hope. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you look at your own `DataFiltrada`? They're all the same, not reflecting your `x` column which suggests filtering. Perhaps you shouldn't hard-code the number `1` for indexing. Also, `filter_` is deprecated. Really, is your data coming to you with these expression-like strings, or are you generating them yourself?

Comment: I generate these expression. Yes, sorry. I modifed [[ 1 ]] --> [[ i ]]. This work, but I want to do it with purrr functional programming.

Comment: Relying on `eval` is prone to many problems, so it is generally discouraged. Since you are generating those yourself, it makes much much more send to me for you to instead do `Data <- tibble(x=c('a','b','c'),y=c(1,2,3))` and then `left_join(Data, othertbl, by = c("x", "y"))`. Is there more complication to your intended logic?